# _eq permission value against ID in different table?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, hasura

I'm setting up some permissions in hasura, I have an 'assigned' table which maps an assigned item to a user, I require the user to be able to only access items they have been assigned. I figured the best way to do this was with the _exists operator where I have:

```
{"_exists":{"_table":{"name":"assigned_item","schema":"public"},"_where":{"_and":[{"userid":{"_eq":"X-Hasura-User-Id"}},{"feed_item_id":{"_eq":"XXX"}}]}}
```

My issue comes into play with the last _eq: XXX - I need for it to equal the value from the item table.

The permission is being created against the assigned item.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `assigned_item` table has `userid` and `feed_item_id` .. your permissions should be:

1. on the `assigned_item` table, just add the permission: `userid _eq X-Hasura-User-Id` as in "A user can see all their assigned items".
2. on the `feed_items?` table, use the relationship to reach the `user_id` through the `assigned_item` table. Assuming the relationship on feed_items is called say "assigned_users", then the permission is: `feed_items > assigned_users > user_id _eq X-Hasura-User-Id`